# System time is off in Fedora

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, fedora, time

I have a desktop PC with Fedora, Ubuntu and Windows installed and grub used for multibooting. But time in Fedora is always 5 hours behind. If I change the time in Fedora, then Windows and Ubuntu will be 5 hours ahead of the current time. I don't understand how to fix it.

Any ideas? All the timezone settings in Fedora, Ubuntu and Windows are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use UTC instead of localtime or vica versa (in Fedora that is).

Check `/etc/sysconfig/clock` for settings. (use `sudo gedit /etc/sysconfig/clock`)

Oh, there is a cute howto also: http://fadvisor.net/blog/2008/06/fedora-9-and-utclocaltime-time-problem/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem in Fedora 12 by choosing System | Administration | Date & Time | Time Zone, unticking 'System clock uses UTC' and then adjusting the time correctly.